# Array pointers assignmnet to 2-D array

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

```
void  main()
  {
    int a[][4]={ 5,7,5,9,
                 4,6,3,1,
                 2,9,0,6};
    int *p;
    int *q [4];
    p=(int *)a;
    q=a;
    printf("\n %u %u",p,q);
    p++;
    q++;
    printf("\n %u %u",p,q);
}
```

My query is can we assign 2-D array to the array of pointers. The above code shows error as
**1.c: In function ‘main’:
1.c:14:6: error: assignment to expression with array type**

Comment: The declaration of `q` is incorrect.  It needs to be `int (*q)[4];`  The parentheses are necessary to force the correct grouping.  That way it will be a pointer to an array of `int`, rather than an array of pointers to `int`.

Comment: Stop casting when you get warnings. Casts aren't silver bullets. `p=(int *)a` should be `p = a[0];` . The code should exhibit evidence that you know what you're doing; not cast to hide warnings indicating you don't.

Answer (score 1):

In C language, arrays are not first class citizens:

- an array *decays* to a pointer when it is used in an expression
- you can never assign to an array

If `q` is an array of pointer, the answer is no, you cannot assign to an array.

If you want `q` to be a *pointer to arrays*, you must declare it as `int (*q)[4];`:

```
int(*q)[4];
q = a;
```

You can then use it to access elements of `a`: `q[i][j]` is the same as `a[i][j]` (and `q[i]` the same as `q[j]`)

Comment: "and `q[i]` the same as `q[j]`" - did you mean the same as `a[i]`?